# I am making custom dataset but finetuning issue happened

Tags: python

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mixtrain.py", line 168, in 
train(10)
File "mixtrain.py", line 110, in train
loss.backward()
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\imbalance\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py", line 245, in backward
torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\imbalance\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd_*init*_.py", line 147, in backward
allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED when calling `cublasCreate(handle)`

I think this error has happened with this part of code

```
net=torchvision.models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
num_class=10+int(args.ratio*10)
net.fc=nn.Linear(net.fc.in_features,num_class)
net=net.cuda('cuda')
```

I am making a custom dataset that mixes cifar100 and mnist as the same data loader. so my number of classes is dynamic as a mixing ratio. but guess back propagation doesn't work because not matching parameters. every dataset has the same dimension also(32x32,  I checked it already)

Comment: You could try running this snippet on CPU first to better locate the problem (and likely to get a more detailed error message)